# AllJoyn open source applications?

Tags: android, alljoyn

I'm trying to find open source AllJoyn based applications. All I got is several apps that repeatedly appear in various sites, but none of them are open source.
https://www.alljoyn.org/app-developers/featured-apps

Of course there are the AllJoyn SDK's sample application, but they are pretty basic.

So, does anyone know about an open source AllJoyn project, preferably intended for Android OS?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at some example projects:

- https://github.com/tkellogg/alljoyn-examples
- https://github.com/JavierT/Alljoyn_signal_sample
- https://github.com/youngkin/FileTransferSampleApp

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code of the LSF and OnBoarding service framework for **Android**

https://github.com/JunaidBabu/AllJoyn_LSF-sample

https://github.com/JunaidBabu/AllJoyn-Onboarding_base

I've imported all the AllJoyn libraries possible which are useless in the cases above but the code does it's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

These are .NET / UWP based. You didn't specifically say Android apart from the Tag, but in any case they might be helpful to you still, since a lot of the code lower level is the same still:

Philips-Hue-to-AllJoyn Bridge https://github.com/dotMorten/AllJoynPhilipsHueDSB

AllJoyn Device Simulator (for simulating various devices, also available in the Windows Store): https://github.com/dotMorten/AllJoynDeviceSimulator

Lighting Controller Framework implementation (Light scenes, groups etc): https://github.com/dotMorten/AllJoynLightingController

.NET Client Library(this includes app for interacting with devices which you can also get in the Windows Store, and is useful for testing services): https://github.com/dotMorten/AllJoynClientLib

Ecobee-to-AllJoyn Bridge: https://github.com/dotMorten/AllJoynEcobeeDSB

AllJoyn.NET/Xamarin Wrapper around the C SDK: Supports Xamarin, including Android: https://github.com/dotMorten/AllJoynDotNet